# Weblogic DB2 data Shows up as '?????' Question Marks

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, jax-rs, weblogic-10.x

I am running Weblogic 10.3.3 with DB2 z/os and Unicode database, for both my local and development servers.

When I run my application locally, the query to the database returns some of the unicode data as question marks, like this '??? ?? ???????'.

This seems to be happening to the Japanese characters.

However if I deploy the code to the development server the code works fine. I can view the characters in my local browser and they show up.

Has anyone seen this before?

I can not figure out what is different between the servers. The drivers and datasources are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, I've been there. You need to add,

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

to your Weblogic startup script. I found the answer at this blog http://alexrogan.com/?p=126

Answer (score 0):

Your code is apparently relying on the platform default encoding when handling the characters. The development server seems to be using UTF-8 while your local development seems to use something different, Windows CP1252 for example, which doesn't support the Japanese characters.

To fix it accordingly, you need to add this to top of every JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Or when you're using Servlets to emit HTML (or other content), then you need to add this before you ever call `getWriter()`

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Or when you're using JAX-RS (as I see in one of your tags), then you need to append the `charset` to the `@Produces` content type.

```
@Produces("application/xml;charset=UTF-8")
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: I also notice that the console output in eclipse does not display utf-8 characters

Comment: This is an Eclipse setting. It uses the platform default encoding by default as well. *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*. For more detail and screens, checkout the "See also" link at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: But in the elcipse editor I was able to add this code as source String input = "日本語"; System.out.println("Original input string from client: " + input); And it comes out in the console as '???' even after I set eclipse to utf8